# install with NPM on Google Drive File stream

Tags: node.js, npm, google-drive-file-stream

I'm developing Node.js app.

I save all of the files on the Google Drive File Stream and it works very well.

But when try to install some package with NPM in terminal, it makes error.

Maybe terminal on VS Code cannot make new directory in Google DFS.

```
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/cli/issues>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-05T00_13_21_425Z-debug.log
```

I can do it in my local drive folder and copy it again to DFS but it's little annoying.

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

1. I am using **Google drive Desktop App**. There only I am saving all my codes.
2. When I was installing a python-shell npm package. I found, **empty files** inside -> The path **node_modules/python-shell**
3. So I copied, entire folder of my code and saved it in Desktop (I mean you can save the files in Local)

Then I installed python-shell package correctly